# How can I move an image based on a timer?

Tags: java, image, swing, timer, paint

How can I move an image based on a timer? I'm trying to get the image to move *without any user input* but I've done something wrong because I cant get the image to move.

Am I  incorrectly calling the method `AnimationPanel` that I've built to actually move the image? I have a feeling it has something to do with that.

Here's what I've tried so far: The *Overloaded Constructor* is so that I can call `AnimationPanel` with ease from this particular class.

```
public class ClassC extends Component {
    int x; int y;
    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
    }

    public ClassC() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("RobotFrame1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public ClassC(int x)
    {}

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null)+900, img.getHeight(null)+900);
        }
    }

    public void AnimationPanel() {

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                x++;
                y++;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        f.add(new ClassC());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        ClassC callanimation = new ClassC(1);
        callanimation.AnimationPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is, why AWT?

Comment: Related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13795187/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component that is on the screen is not the component that you are animating...

```
// Create first instance here...
f.add(new ClassC());
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
// Create second instance here...
ClassC callanimation = new ClassC(1);
callanimation.AnimationPanel();
```

Instead, this will get you started

```
ClassC callanimation = new ClassC();
callanimation.AnimationPanel();
f.add(callanimation);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

ps- I'd also be very careful, you are mixing frameworks.  While AWT and Swing share some parts of the library, they don't always play nice together ;)

Comment: Im so sorry for wasting your time. My mind must not be in the right mode today. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to my world :P

Comment: @moonbeamer2234 : Instead of adding a `WindowListener` to the `JFrame`, it would be wise, if you just write `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`, that will do almost the same task :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw `java.awt.Frame` doesn't have `setDefaultCloseOperation`.  This would assume that the OP was using Swing ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer : But inside the main method I am watching `JFrame` being used ...

Comment: @nIcEcOw Sorry, you're right, keep getting caught on the "using AWT" part, my bad - another reason the OP should be using a `JPanel`

Answer (score 3):

```
public ClassC(int x)
{

}
```

why is this empty? what is x for?

```
f.add(new ClassC()); <-- you created a ClassC() here
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
ClassC callanimation = new ClassC(1); <-- you created a new ClassC here
```

these two are different because you created them again..

try doing:

```
ClassC callanimation = new ClassC(1);
f.add(callanimantion); 
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
callanimation.AnimationPanel();
```