# Making a screensaver using circles.. How do i make a loop for circles so that new circles get created?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, bluej

Hiya I'm doing a screensaver in BlueJ .. and i have made few circles but need to make a loop so that new circles get created at random points although i m not sure how to do it.. this is how much i have done.

```
public class ScreenSaver
     {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private Circle a;
    private Circle b;
    private Circle c;
    private Circle d;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ScreenSaver
     */
    public ScreenSaver()
       {
        // initialise instance variables
        //x = 0;
       }
    public void draw()
       {
        a = new Circle();
        a.moveVertical(70);
        a.changeSize(70);
        a.slowMoveVertical(-100);
        a.makeVisible();

        b= new Circle();
        b.changeColor("red");
        b.moveHorizontal(30);
        b.makeVisible();
        b.slowMoveVertical(-100);
        b.slowMoveVertical(100);

       }
```

How do I get to make loops so that new circles get created at random points?

Comment: First of all, sorry that you have to use bluej.  Why don't you try a few things, then if you are still stuck go to the CS lab.

Comment: *"I'm doing a screensaver"*  You're about 7 years late for SaverBeans (the Java screensaver API).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795236/get-mouse-detection-with-a-dynamic-shape/13796268#13796268) for creating multiple ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer based solely on "what's closest to what you have right now" and that would be to enclose the code in `draw()` in a `while` loop that goes on and on until something happens.

To make the circles appear in random places, you could create a `new java.util.Random()` just before the `while` loop and call its `nextInt(int)` method in every iteration to get a pseudo random integer and force it to be in your desired range.

Answer (score 0):

Use class Random:

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(screenWith);
int y = random.nextInt(screenyheight);
int radius = minradius + random.nextInt(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an advocate for loops like this:

```
while(true)
{
    //code goes here
    if (<something happens>)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

What this does is it keeps going forever and then breaks the loop when the `if` statement comes `true`. You have have this as a `waitForClick()` method or something along those lines. As well, it has been stated to use the `Random` class for the random points. Just my suggestion!

I hope this helps :)