# How can I get my image to flip?

Tags: java, image

I'm having a problem getting an image to flip. My program is supposed to show the default image and the flipped image. I thought that if I could replace the (0,0) pixel of the flipped picture with the (width-1,height-1) of the original picture, it would work, but instead of getting the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGqiS.jpg), I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcgTq.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Horizontal {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Picture source = new Picture(args[0]);//name of picture.
    Picture flip = new Picture(source.width(), source.height());//sets the width and height of source

    for (int i =0; i < source.width(); i++)
    {
        int w = 1;
        int sw = source.width()-w;
        for (int j = 0; j < source.width(); j++)
        {
            int h=1;
            int sh =  source.height()-h;
            Color SourceColor =  source.get(sw,sh);// return the the color pixel of (sw,sh)
            flip.set(i, j, SourceColor);//suppose to replace the (i,j) pixel of flip with source's (sw,sh) pixel
            h++;
        }
        w++;
    }
    source.show();// shows the original image
    flip.show(); // shows flipped version of image
}
```

}

Comment: your images are broken... cant see what it looks like

Comment: This it typically done using a couple of `AffineTransfroem` instances as shown in (for e.g.) [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742365/how-do-i-flip-an-image-horizontally-flip-with-glreadpixels-bufferedimage-and-o/13756357#13756357).  BTW - what is the `Picture` class and where does it come from?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: is that the background color?

Comment: @Chanckjh no, its supposed to be the flipped image. It was supposed to replace each pixel in the original image and put it into the flipped one. but it didn't work out that way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the Picture class is from this [page](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Picture.java.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chceck this site. It has great info about basic image algorithms in java. 
You can copy code for flipping an image.

http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/#9

Flipping horizontally:

```
public static BufferedImage horizontalflip(BufferedImage img) {  

    int w = img.getWidth();  
    int h = img.getHeight();  
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());  
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, w, 0, 0, h, null);  
    g.dispose();  
    return dimg;  
}
```

Flipping vertically:

```
public static BufferedImage verticalflip(BufferedImage img) {  
        int w = img.getWidth();  
        int h = img.getHeight();  
        BufferedImage dimg = dimg = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getColorModel().getTransparency());  
        Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, 0, h, w, 0, null);  
        g.dispose();  
        return dimg;  
    }
```