# Java shapes convert to BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, bufferedimage

I want to make rectangles on a JLabel and the convert that rectangle into a BufferedImage... like layers in paint shop... drage that BufferedImage and resize...can anyone help

I have done this but it didnt work

```
Rectangle2D rectangle2D;
                            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(bimg.getWidth(), bimg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                            Graphics2D big = bi.createGraphics();
                            rectangle2D = new Rectangle2D.Float(eX, eY, sW, sH);
                            big.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
                            big.setColor(color);
                            shapePaint = new TexturePaint(bi, rectangle2D);
                            g2d.setPaint(shapePaint);
```

Comment: You mean you want something like vector based rectangle then?

Answer (score 5):

> I want to make rectangles on a JLabel and the convert that rectangle into a BufferedImage

You are doing it the wrong way around.  Draw to the buffered image, add it to a label, call `label.repaint()` to display any changes.

#### E.G.

As seen in..

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055306/418556)
   [image]
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13756357/418556)
   [image]
3. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) or..
   [image]
4. ..For an animated version, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628553/418556)
   [image]

Comment: See edit to answer, which links to 4 SSCCEs.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of *your* best attempt.

Comment: Well like I said yesterday.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you ***read*** the linked document, or are you just ***guessing*** what SSCCE means?